# how i can develop a exeternal service?

Tags: android, service, android-intent, android-ndk

how I can develop a service that I can call from any application from any where

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Using the intent reply: `intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");` you will take the QR content.
Now you can analyze the String. If this starts with:

- "BEGIN:VCARD" it has find a Vcard
- "TEL:" it has find a telephone number
- "SMSTO:" it is a SMS
- "HTTP://" or "HTTPS://" it has find an URL

In other cases it will be a text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import the Android code, and in fact should not. This is how you integrate: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent  You can see how the result type and other metadata come back with the intent reply.